# When ever I call API through any event it scroll top of the window in ANGULAR 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, scroll

I have a button on a component that will filter my table while doing so I am calling an API. After the API is called it scroll top to the window. But I want that it should stay in its original position.

POINT TO NOTICE: I am not using scroll CSS or any javascript.

**.ts  File**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.type = 'all';
    this.getCandidateDetails(this.type);
 }

 getLoggedInuserDetails(type) {
    this.sharedService.getCandidateDetails(type).subscribe(res => {
      this.User = res.data;
    });
 }

 getFemaleCandidateDetails(){
    this.type = 'female';
    this.getCandidateDetails(this.type);
 }
```

**.html file**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getFemaleCandidateDetails()">Overall</button>
<table>
// Here I am rendring the data
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code so we can have an idea ?

Comment: You may submitted a form that caused the page to refresh.

Comment: This might be because of refreshing the entire data. If you are using ngFor, try to add trackByIndex option

Comment: Is your table is the only component bin the page that is displayed in the body of the page. If yes then if the body is not big enough then it would always scroll to the top as their is nothing in the table and when the data is populated the page is in start position

Comment: Is your table is the only component bin the page that is displayed in the body of the page. If yes then if the body is not big enough then it would always scroll to the top as their is nothing in the table and when the data is populated the page is in start position